# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status -1073740791

Tags: python, selenium

I had a functioning web scraping tool in selenium and then I suddenly started getting the following error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status -1073740791

Sample Code:

---

```
opts = FirefoxOptions();
opts.add_argument("--headless");
opts.log.level = "trace";
opts.binary = 'C:\\Users\\PATH\\firefox.exe';
driver = Firefox(executable_path='C:\\Users\\PATH...\\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=opts);
```

'''

---

I'm using the firefox geckodriver and have tried running headless and not headless.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: this error arises when Firefox cannot open a new window. I uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox and got the error to be resolved.